# Magento grid column change align to center in number type

Tags: magento

When you are using the number type in Magento's grid column:

```
    $this->addColumn('my_number',
        array(
            'header' =>Mage::helper('bidashboard')->__('My number'),
            'index' => 'my_number',
            'total' => 'sum',
            'align' => 'center',
            'type' => 'number',
            'sortable' => false,
        ));
```

It seems the 'align' has no affect on it. It is because the align hard-coded on the number type renderer:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Number
...
public function renderCss()
{
    return parent::renderCss() . ' a-right';
}
...
```

So how do I change the align in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The a-right class in the default Magento 1.7.0.2 css file:
/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css
in line 77 has

.a-right {
  text-align: left !important;
}

so I guess overwriting this css class in your theme's css file will fix this.

Like this:

```
body.checkout-cart-index .a-right {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

or this:

```
body.checkout-cart-index #shopping-cart-table td:nth-child(7) {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

Comment: It is not good solution, as .a-right class probably also used in other places. thank you anyway.

Comment: To make sure this is overwritten on only one page - for example the cart page, simply add this information to your css. Magento provides different class for most of its pages.

Comment: You are right. For other side, it could confuse the future developers to understand what is going on, as it says .a-right but for some reason it align to left... This why I don't like much this way. +1 to you any way! Thank you.